# Como criar uma imagem com efeito hover no C#

Tags: c#, css-hover

To fazendo um aplicativo e queria que ao passar o mouse na imagem, ela mudasse a cor para uma mais clara, mas nao consigo fazer isso no C#...

Comment: um aplicativo, mas ele seria um sistema web correto? pois voce diz sobre "passar ou mouse"

Comment: Se for aplicação web vc deveria utilizar o evento oumouseover do javascript e mudar a cor

Comment: windows? web? por favor especifique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você estiver usando C# WindowsForms, com uma imagem sendo exibida em uma PictureBox, é possível manipular o evento MouseHover e o evento MouseLeave.

```
private void PictureBox1_MouseHover(object objeto, EventArgs evento){
   //Aqui você manipula o mouse sobre da PictureBox
```

}

```
private void PictureBox1_MouseLeave(object objeto, EventArgs evento){
   //Aqui você manipula a saida mouse da PictureBox
```

}